# Printer status showing 'offline' after registering to Google cloud print

Tags: printers, google-cloud-print

I am working on server side (Receiving print jobs to printer); I am following the developers guide mentioned as "https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/devguide#registering"
I am able to register/add printer to google cloud. Got a register_token;
I am able to claim the ownership of the printer and then till refresh and access tokens.

The printer I am just adding, I am able to see in my printers list through browser.
But, the status of it remains 'offline'. I am really wondering if I am missing some basic thing. How to make this printer online

Comment: It's a long time, but did you find a solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Printer come to online when we restart computer and sign in again but it does not work always :(